# BX-Slider and equal heights on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nWV5P/7/

Why is my `.gallerySliderImageText` not expanding correct, when using equalHeight() on it?

I also have it here in its real world setting:
http://www.nnf.dk/testside/

2nd slide shows that it don't expand, 
I can see in chrome dev tools, that the height is set correctly, but its just not expanding.

But if i fx resize the window, the div pops out and expands.

Comment: I now see that you're using an equal heights script on the div. That won't work because any script that calculates heights must see the divs it's calculating, so anything hidden won't work. Equal Heights won't work in tabs, accordions, or sliders. Or it works, but only on the first one, it won't take the height of the second non-showing div since it doesn't show.

Comment: Well if you use chrome dev tool you can see that i does set the correct height on all, so they are vissible to the DOM.. they arrent hidden.. they are just moved out of sight.. so doubt that being the problem either..

Comment: Yes, I see that. If you append an &nbsp it takes on the heights. http://jsfiddle.net/AnAP4/

Comment: Thanks, thats an okay temporary fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem..

The generated div with class: `.bx-viewport`, get's a specific height, so i needed to change that, to allow the inner div to expand.